# Inherit selector from parent

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I'm trying to create a parent class (Event) that will handle the DOM for four children (vote-event, view-event, my-events, my-votes).

The idea would be to have an only HTML, a parent Compoment, and 4 children Component that will override some parent methods. It's the typical polymorphism case.

Anyhow, i have a parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-events',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})

export abstract class EventsComponent implements OnInit{
    constructor() {};
    ngOnInit() {
        this.test();
    }
    abstract test();
}
```

A parent HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div class="container pad-top">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 nopadding text-center">
      <a [routerLink]="['/events/vote-events']"><img class="img-responsive sin-looks-votacion"
                                                     src="assets/images/no-tienes-votaciones.jpg"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I would like to do something like:

Child Component:

```
export class MyVotesComponent extends EventsComponent {

    private potato;

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    test() {
      console.log("Testttttttttttt");
    }
}
```

Child HTML:

```
<app-events></app-events>
```

The thing is, I had to remove the EventsComponent from the `events.module.ts` declarations. And now the browser will throw:

```
'app-events' is not a known element:
```

The final question would be: Is this the best approach? If not, what would be? What should I read into? And if it is indeed the best approach, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

All the best,

Alejandro

Comment: why do you extend components?

Comment: I am not 100% following... maybe a usecase for `ng-content` or `@ContentChildren` ?

Comment: @Aravind I want to extend the parent component in order to avoid duplicate code in the children components.

@Jeff Could you further elaborate please? What would `@ContentChildren` or `ng-content` do. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll have to duplicate the `templateUrl` and `styleUrls` on the `@Component` decorator of each subclass. But at least you can keep the files in one place:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-votes',
  templateUrl: './events.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./events.component.css']
})
export class MyVotesComponent extends EventsComponent {

    private potato;

    constructor() {
      super();
    }

    test() {
      console.log("Testttttttttttt");
    }
}
```

You'll probably want to remove the `@Component` decorator from your abstract base class.

Comment: I'll give it a try, it's definitely worth a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, sorry for the delay in my answer. I was out for the weekend and didn't have time to fiddle with the code. This indeed solved my problem, and was able to succesfully re-utilize the same html and parent component. Cheers!